# Mat-Table overlapping menu above when scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-table, mat-tab

I've got a `mat-toolbar` placed above a `mat-table` inside a `mat-tab`, I'd like to keep the toolbar and the table headers visible at all times, however, when I scroll down the page, the toolbar becomes overlapped with the table.  The headers scroll up to the top of the `mat-tab` and I can't seem to get the table headers to stop at the bottom of the mat-toolbar.

Looking around, people have suggested using the sticky position css property, which works to keep my toolbar visible, but the table headers still overlap.  I'm not sure how to fix this.  Example below:

**Image of header position before scroll**
[image: Image of header position before scroll]

**Image of header position after scroll**
[image: Image of header position after scroll]

**Layout**

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <div fxLayout="column">
            <mat-toolbar fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start space-between" ngClass="table-toolbar sticky-top">
                ....BUTTONS....
            </mat-toolbar>
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                    ....TABLE....
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="columns: columns;"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Styles**

```
.table-toolbar {
    height: 80px !important;
    padding-left: 24px !important;
    min-height: 80px !important;
}

.sticky-top {
    top: 0 !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important; // This only makes it appear above or below the table
    position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try overriding the mat-table header top position. Normally it is set to 0, You could override to the pixels you need. Here is the example.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/glmqladoole

```css
.mat-table-sticky{
  top:80px !important;

}
```

Comment: This was a very simple way to get it to work, however, if your component uses variable sized headers (i.e. if you have a toolbar + filter row on one component and just a toolbar on another) then this will only address a static set size. I'll mark this as the answer for now, but I believe this could be made more dynamic.

Comment: In my case, I had to set the top property of mat-table-sticky class to minus value which ultimately resolved the issue.